# C++ va_list returning odd values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a form of reflection in C++ for a project. The idea is that you register classes with tags into a map as a sort of template, then call the cloneNew method of the shared base class to actually create the object that you want. However when I try to use a va_list to implement this functionality I get weird results. The problem code is:

```
GameObject* SphereObstacle::cloneNew(const Vector& position, double charge, const Vector&         dipole, ...)
{
    va_list v1;
    va_start(v1, dipole);
    double radius = va_arg(v1, double);
    va_end(v1);
    return new SphereObstacle(position, charge, dipole, radius);
}
```

Every time I try to read from the va_list it returns a value that is huge. It almost seems like its a pointer. My only thought is that the issue is caused by the fact that this is an implementation of a virtual method in the base class, but I haven't found anything online to suggest that that is the issue. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `dipole` being of a reference type. Regarding `va_start`, citing [support.runtime]/3:

> The parameter parmN is the identifier of the rightmost parameter
>   in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the ...). If the parameter
>   parmN is declared with a function, array, or reference type, or with a type that is not compatible with the
>   type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Ah ok, so putting the charge argument last should solve the issue then? Can you pass additional reference arguments within the ellipsis or is that an issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration like ...

GameObject* SphereObstacle::cloneNew(const Vector& position, double charge, Vector dipole, ...)